# WP8 In-app purchase - one durable product

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I Have tried and tested just about every sample and tutorial that i can find, i'm just looking to have a button when purchase is complete it sets a bool to false, its one durable product. Any advice would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft wrote some tutorial how to do it. You have to get information about bought products and then check some conditions that are described there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206950%28v=vs.105%29.aspx